Want to build moving average with an external source
upTrend =    plot(direction < 3 ? supertrend : 1, "Trend 1", linewidth= 2  ,color = #070bfc, style = plot.style_linebr,editable = false)
now
sma= (length=36, source= uptrend)
i dont want close, open, hl2, ohlc4,etc etc. i want to use that line as source.
how to make this scenario possible. what argument should i write to make this possible?
i tried above mentioned but it is not accepting it. i was expecting that now trading view gives access to external source so i can change it in pinescript also. but unable to do it.
